# Why is the On Click Listener Crashing my Android application?

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, onclicklistener

So, as a bit of background, I am currently an iOS developer, and I wanted to branch out and develop for android as well, and I finally found time to do so.

I've been watching some video tutorials on developing for android, and in the lesson we made a simple app that when you click one button it adds 1 and when you click another it subtracts.

There's also a small textview which the number value of the total changes as well when the button is clicked, all of which can be easily identified in the code.

However, when I build and run the app, it displays an error on the screen saying "Unfortunately (Name of app) has stopped."

Add upon debugging the app only stops working and displays this message after I add my first On Click Listener method.

**Here is the main XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0" 
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
/>
    <Button 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add One"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
/>     

    <Button 
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subtract One"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
/>   


</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the Manifest XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tutorial.thenewboston"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Here is the Java:**

```
public class StartingPoint extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

**Here is the LogCat:**

```
03-14 14:53:41.111: D/AndroidRuntime(17884): Shutting down VM
03-14 14:53:41.111: W/dalvikvm(17884): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ce4ba8)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884): Process: com.tutorial.thenewboston, PID: 17884
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutorial.thenewboston/com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:31)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-14 14:53:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(17884):    ... 11 more
```

**Console Log:**

```
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] ------------------------------
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] Android Launch!
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] Performing com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint activity launch
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] Automatic Target Mode: using device '015d483bce140216'
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-03-14 15:09:31 - TheNewBoston] Starting activity com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint on device 015d483bce140216
[2014-03-14 15:09:32 - TheNewBoston] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.tutorial.thenewboston/.StartingPoint }
```

And here is some more hopefully relevant information:
I'm testing my apps on my personal Android Tablet not the Simulator, because the sim is dirt slow.
My tablet is an Asus Nexus 7, with NVIDIA Tegra 3 1.20GHz
1GB RAM, 32GB Flash Storage
and is running Kit Kat, 4.4.2

***EDIT:***

My previous java contained an error which was linking it to my main XML view.
it was calling activity_starting_point when it should have been calling fragment_starting_point.

**This is the new code**

```
public class StartingPoint extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_starting_point);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
```

However my problem is the exact same, the app crashes with the same message as before, but it does contain new logcat info:

```
03-14 15:25:44.621: E/FragmentManager(20269): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.tutorial.thenewboston:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4247a988 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-14 15:25:44.621: E/FragmentManager(20269): Activity state:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):   Local FragmentActivity 4245cf60 State:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     mLoadersStarted=false
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):   Active Fragments in 4245e0b8:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{4247a988 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{4245e0b8 in StartingPoint{4245cf60}}
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       mActivity=com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint@4245cf60
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):   Added Fragments:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{4247a988 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):   FragmentManager misc state:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     mActivity=com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint@4245cf60
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@4245ea30
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):   View Hierarchy:
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{424636b0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):       com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{424646a0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
03-14 15:25:44.621: D/FragmentManager(20269):         android.widget.FrameLayout{42465448 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):           android.widget.LinearLayout{42472528 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):             android.widget.TextView{42472840 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003d app:id/tvDisplay}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):             android.widget.Button{42472e30 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003e app:id/bAdd}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):             android.widget.Button{42473838 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003f app:id/bSub}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{42465960 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{42465fb8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):             android.widget.LinearLayout{42466718 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{42467a90 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):                 android.widget.ImageView{42467f58 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102025a android:id/up}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):                 android.widget.ImageView{42469038 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):               android.widget.LinearLayout{4246a3f0 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):                 android.widget.TextView{4246a890 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):                 android.widget.TextView{4246b578 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020266 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{4246bc60 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/action_context_bar}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/FragmentManager(20269):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{4246c248 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020317 android:id/split_action_bar}
03-14 15:25:44.631: D/AndroidRuntime(20269): Shutting down VM
03-14 15:25:44.631: W/dalvikvm(20269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ce4ba8)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269): Process: com.tutorial.thenewboston, PID: 20269
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutorial.thenewboston/com.tutorial.thenewboston.StartingPoint}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.tutorial.thenewboston:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4247a988 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.tutorial.thenewboston:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{4247a988 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
03-14 15:25:44.631: E/AndroidRuntime(20269):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Might be useful for you to get help to copy the xml and log into the question instead of screenshot.

Comment: I tried before, and it didn't look quite right, but I'll try again.

Comment: Check your display var, sometimes when you call thing on the onCreate the screen isn`t already build. It seems to me you have a null pointer in this line "display.setText("Your total is " + counter);" can you config what you have on the line 31?

Comment: Which is line 31 in code

Comment: Just initialize your counter as 0 before the on create and remove the counter = 0 from onCreate() and then just increment the value counter ++ and set your textview as display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

Comment: @mike20132013 I can be wrong, so tell me if I miss something here, but in java an int var can't be null since this var is a primitive object so the var will always have a value, in the case of an int value this default value will be 0

Comment: True.. i don't think there's anything wrong with your code..Can you do one thing, just put a log before setting the text text and run it.. see what you get in the console. Put log as Log.i("Counter Count :", String.valueOf(counter));

Comment: I'm sure the problem is with the display being null

Comment: @mike20132013 I'll edit my question to contain the console log content as well.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either; Try checking your configuration for the Emulator or something in your Manifest file (Using ActionBarActivity ??)

Comment: @Eenvincible I'm not using an emulator, I'm using my physical Nexus 7. My manifest file looks fine to me, but I can post the xml from it in case I'm missing something.

Comment: The counter is working fine in my case too.. I don't see an issue here with your code. However, I didn't set the counter as 0 in onCreate()..all i did was : int counter; then in the on click, set the counter as counter++ and set the value in the textview

Comment: @mike20132013 it doesn't seem to me like that should matter, but I'll be more than glad to give that a shot. It seems cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

I just watched the tutoiral:

**You are setting the wrong layout file:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
```

**You are supposed to set:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Assuming what you are saying in your question is correct and the XML code you posted really belongs to "main.xml". This is why you are getting a `NullPointerException`. The Views (TextView, Button, ...) you are trying to reference **are not in the layout file** you set as the content view.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but my main is the activity starting point. Same file just named differently due to his tutorials being outdated, eclipse sets things up a bit differently.

Comment: I dont know what your layoutfiles are named. Just set the one that actually contains your buttons and textview as the content view.

Comment: You're right my content view was incorrectly named, mine is fragment_starting_point. However, that did not fix my problem :/.

Comment: You should be getting a different error now. If not, you did not fix it correctly. Again: You need to use the layout file that actually contains your buttons and textview as the content view of your activity. Is your error ocurring at app start, of after you click a button?

Comment: It was previously occurring at app start, and is still occurring at app start. You are correct though, there is a new error, I will update my question to contain the details.

Comment: Allright, whats your new error message? (Logcat output)

Comment: Remove: if (savedInstanceState == null) { ... and so on ... } and it will compile and run.

Comment: I believe I do, the view was not loading because it was not linked to the correct xml. After linking the xml the if statement was causing an issue, and I'm assuming it has something to deal with the Fragment manager not agreeing with the fragment_starting_point. Since it was unneeded, removing that bit of code allowed the program to run with no problem.

Comment: You are almost right. You second crash occurred because the R.id.container was not in the xml. file you set as the content view.

Comment: Oh, now that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);


            }
        });
```

Regards.
Jose